# Round() not enough

Tags: r

```
  Class_1 Class_2 Class_3 Class_4 Class_5 Class_6 Class_7 Class_8 Class_9
    0.002   0.326   0.224   0.402   0.004   0.006   0.030   0.002   0.004
    0.012   0.026   0.022   0.004   0.010   0.600   0.024   0.278   0.024
    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.994   0.000   0.004   0.002
    0.008   0.528   0.300   0.078   0.000   0.002   0.008   0.014   0.062
    0.142   0.004   0.002   0.000   0.002   0.044   0.010   0.320   0.476
    0.000   0.086   0.914   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

Hello. Df above is what I'm working with. I want to round each row so that each row has exactly one "1" under the class with the largest decimal. Using the round() function makes all row entries 0 if all values are below .5; for example, the first row is all 0 using round() since all are rounded down using round(). Seems like I'll have to use an if statement.

```
> dput(head(demo56.pred))
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 
9L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("Class_1", 
"Class_2", "Class_3", "Class_4", "Class_5", "Class_6", "Class_7", 
"Class_8", "Class_9")))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a data.frame or a matrix? It would also help if you ran `dput` on the object and provided the output, to make it reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html), which applies a function to every row of a data frame or matrix.

```
t(apply(yourdata, 1, function(r) as.numeric(r == max(r))))
```

---

The way this works is that:

- `r == max(r)` will create a logical vector (`TRUE` and `FALSE`) about whether each value in `r` is the highest one.
- `as.numeric(r == max(r))` turns the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values into 1 and 0, respectively.
- `apply(yourdata, 1, function(r) as.numeric(r == max(r)))` applies this function to each row of the data frame or matrix. The `1` tells `apply` to apply it to the rows (`2` would have applied it to the columns).
- Finally, `apply` returns one column for each row in the original data. You want to transpose it back, which is why it's wrapped in `t`.

Comment: @mbs1 That means there are ties for the maximum. What do you want to do with ties (which one should be `1`?)

Comment: It is not working for rows where there is a unique max

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your matrix using `dput`? (Run `dput(yourdata)`, or if the data is large run `dput(head(yourdata))`, and edit your question to paste in the output)

Comment: @mbs1 Incidentally, if you use `head` please make sure to include at least a few rows that aren't working

Comment: @mbs1 I don't think `demo56.pred` is your original data (since it's all 0s and 1s), I think it's your rounded data. That is likely the problem. Apply my solution above to your original data, not the rounded data.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `pmax`

```
(df1==do.call(pmax, df1))+0L
#  Class_1 Class_2 Class_3 Class_4 Class_5 Class_6 Class_7 Class_8 Class_9
#[1,]      0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
#[2,]      0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
#[3,]      0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
#[4,]      0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#[5,]      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
#[6,]      0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Class_1 = c(0.002, 0.012, 0, 0.008, 0.142, 0), 
Class_2 = c(0.326, 0.026, 0, 0.528, 0.004, 0.086), Class_3 = c(0.224, 
0.022, 0, 0.3, 0.002, 0.914), Class_4 = c(0.402, 0.004, 0, 
0.078, 0, 0), Class_5 = c(0.004, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.002, 0), 
Class_6 = c(0.006, 
0.6, 0.994, 0.002, 0.044, 0), Class_7 = c(0.03, 0.024, 0, 
0.008, 0.01, 0), Class_8 = c(0.002, 0.278, 0.004, 0.014, 
0.32, 0), Class_9 = c(0.004, 0.024, 0.002, 0.062, 0.476, 
0)), .Names = c("Class_1", "Class_2", "Class_3", "Class_4", 
"Class_5", "Class_6", "Class_7", "Class_8", "Class_9"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```